# Guide to being a good father?

Tags: product-recommendation, children-parenting

Are there any halachic guides to being a good father? Beyond that, a list of well established principles rooted in halacha?

Comment: I've heard of "To Raise a Jewish Child" by Rabbi Hayim Halevi Donin. I hope it helps..

Comment: https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%94_%D7%A7%D7%99%D7%93%D7%95%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%9F_%D7%90_%D7%96

Answer (score 3):

see Rambam Hilchot Deot

he ends off there in [ch.5](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/910345/jewish/Deot-Chapter-Five.htm)

> Whoever conducts himself in this manner [may be assured that] not only
>   does he sanctify his soul, purify himself, and refine his character,
>   but, furthermore, if he has children, they will be handsome and
>   modest, worthy of wisdom and piety.
>
> [In contrast,] whoever conducts himself in the ways of the rest of the
>   people who walk in darkness, will have children like those people.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure exactly what you are looking for, but two good guides for how to raise children are:

Zeriah u'Binyan beChinnuch by Rabbi Shlomo Wolbe

Chovas HaTalmidim by the Piacetzna Rebbe, Kalonymos Kalman Shapira (the whole book is worthwhile both for parenting and one's own growth, but the introduction addresses parents specifically as I recall).